# ConcurrentModificationException on synchronized() code - how is it possible?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I have a following spring bean (a little edited) This bean is responsible for adding/removing websocket connections to an internal connection (this.sockets). New connetions may be added/removed and are iterated each time a message needs to be sent.

As you can see every operation on the `sockets` field is wrapped in a `synchronized()` block it is private and is not used outside of this class, every use of this field is in the code i pasted below.

But still from time to time i am getting an `ConcurrentModificartionException` that happens in the for loop in `onApplicationEvent` call. This call may indeed be called by multiple threads in the application but my understanding was that if every call that actually modifies or iterates on `this.socket` variable is wrapped in synchronized() block on the same object then each of these calls cannot be invoked in parallel and have to "Wait" for each other.

How it is possible that `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown in this code? Bear in mind that i am trying to understand the reason for exception i am getting and i am not looking for a quick fix that will just go around this issue (so answers like 'why dont you use XXX here' do not actually solve anything for me - i  am trying to find out what i did wrong in my code).

The code:

```
public class MyClass extends TextWebSocketHandler implements ApplicationListener<AppEventMessage>{

    private static final Logger log= LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    private Set<WebSocketSession> sockets=new HashSet<>();


    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
        synchronized (this.sockets) {
            this.sockets.add(session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        synchronized (this.sockets) {
            this.sockets.remove(session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AppEventMessage event) {
        synchronized (this.sockets) {
            for (WebSocketSession session : this.sockets) {
                try {
                    log.info("sendin");
                    session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(event.getMessage()));
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    log.warn("error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The most relevant part of stacktrace (with my comments)

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1445)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1469)
    at ...MyClass.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEventWebsocketHandler.java:46) <- (line 46 is the for(WebSocketSession ...) line)
    at ...MyClass.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEventWebsocketHandler.java:19) <- (line 19 is the "public class Myclass" line - how it is possible?)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
```

Comment: First of all, there is no reason why your set should not be final. Hence, I would declare it as final. If the object is not final and it changes the pointer reference while running, even if you had synchronized on it, the JVM would let still pass another thread. So that's the first thing I would fix.

Comment: Second, all your methods synchronize the same object. I would rather synchronize on this and not on this.sockets.

Comment: Third, for the line of the stack trace where you say "how it is possible", bare in mind that what you execute is java bytecode, not the source code directly. When you compile the code, some optimizations may be done by the JVM and so the line number may not be the right one anymore. It's line 19 of the compiled class, not of the source code.

Comment: To conclude: I can't tell you why you get a concurrent modification exception without seeing how the threads are really calling this object, but the first two comments that I left are already something that you should get fixed (and if you still have the issue, then investigate further).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with your diagnosis so far. There is a second way to get a `ConcurrentModificationException` that is commonly overlooked...

Those `synchronized` locks are *re-entrant* which means the thread holding the lock in one method can access all methods. So the thread causing your CME is quite possibly a callback from *within the `for` loop* that ends up back in your connection-listener methods.

IMO, the most likely scenario is that the connection is only detected as closed when trying to `sendMessage`.

Resolution: There are cleverer solutions but this is one that cannot go wrong:

```java
  // Take copy of sockets before iterating it to defend against self-induced ConcurrentModificationException
  for (WebSocketSession session : new HashSet<>(this.sockets)) {
```

Comment: Correct! i have even drilled into the WebsocketSession implementation code and i can see that if the sendMessage method fails it tries to close the session which, in turn executes the afterConnectionClosed handler. So it ends up that during the iteration a afterConnectionClosed is invoked and modifies the set that is iterated on. Thank you it was bugging me for a while :)

Comment: Just a side question - since i see that new HashSet<>(collection) uses addAll which in turn iterates over my collection then even if iterate over new HashSet(this.sockets) i still need to wrap the loop (or at least creation of the copy)  in synchrtonized() block - correct?

Comment: Correct - "creation of the copy" is the code you must still guard

Answer (score 0):

I don't see immediately what could cause the `ConcurrentModificationException`, but here is an advise that may help. instead of synchronizing on `this.sockets` declare in your class a 
`static final Object myLock = new Object();`

And synchronize on that. This object will be the only one and unmodifiable. Better candidate to be a lock. Better yet, read up on classes [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). They provide better synchronization and easier to maintain